# Need to run sql command on iframe load. Preferably not using onload()

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

I would like to run an sql command once an iframe is loaded fully, I have found a way to do this using onload() JS function but it poses a security risk. Users are rewarded in viewing web pages, so a simple hack would be to call the url with the userid amended to it, the url would be visible if I was to use JS. If onload() can be of any use to a solution, that is fine so long as the final result is secure.

The postback script to update the user.

```
include("config.php");  
include("mysql.php");  
$reward = 1;  
$suid   = $_REQUEST['usr'];

mysql_query("UPDATE ".MYSQLTABLE." SET amount=amount+".$reward." WHERE usr='".$suid."'") or die(mysql_error());  
mysql_close();
```

I am newish to php and sql and have come to realised my php/sql book is out of date!

Answer (score 0):

Php will be completed in one flow, except if you're asking data from other services which take some time or you sleep the application. The best is indeed use `onload()` and use an ajax call.

Check [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: so something like this     `function update(){
        $.ajax(
                { url: 'postback.php?usr='$suid'',
                 type : 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success : function ( jsXHR) {
                 },
                 failed : function(status,data){ }
               }
         );
    

});` If so this would be exploitable.

Comment: You could do that, and also save the data hashed in an session / cookie, with a secret key to unhash it, created based on time. Like if I started this process at 13:33, there's a hash based on this time for 10 minutes. You can set a cookie to check what the time is, and unhash it in the endpoint...

Comment: ha I just thought that! Not so much the cookie/session and encryption, that all sounds a bit advanced for me yet, but I've amended the JS to            `postback.php?usr='$suid'&key='$key'` with $key having to match in the postback file. Working on it now :) Cheers for the help!